# Python: "name ascii() is not defined"

Tags: python, encoding

I've executed this from the Python REPL:

```
>>> ascii('Łukasz')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ascii' is not defined
>>>
```

Why isn't a built-in function recognized?

The same thing happen when I executed this script with Python interpreter:

```
#!/user/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

def escape_unicode(f):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        x = f(*args, **kwargs)
        return ascii(x)

    return wrap     

@escape_unicode
def my_name():
    return 'Łukasz'

my_name()
```

> NameError: global name 'ascii' is not defined

Comment: Are you sure you're in 3.X? `ascii` doesn't exist in Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ascii()` function is only [available in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ascii).

Use the [`repr()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr), which does *exactly* what `ascii()` does in Python 3 (`repr()` in Python 3 won't use `\uhhhh` escapes for non-ascii codepoints):

```
>>> print repr(u'Łukasz')
u'\u0141ukasz'
```

If you are following a tutorial, you either need to switch to a different tutorial that teaches Python 2, or install Python 3 and continue to use that instead.

Comment: I'm literally just starting with Python. I knew that the tutorial used Python 3.x, but I wrongly assumed that `ascii()` has been present for a while. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

`ascii` is not a python (2.7) builtin.  Perhaps you're thinking of `str()`, or `s.encode('ascii')`?

Comment: No, they were thinking of using `repr()`.